# Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: laravel

This seems to be a common problem but I can't find an answer that relates directly to this.

I've got a users and designs tables and I'm trying to add a foreign key to the designs table to make it refer to the id on the users table.

The migration for the users table:

```
    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

The migration for the designs table:

```
    Schema::create('designs', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

The migration that I'm trying to do to add the foreign key:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('designs', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
}


/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('designs', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn('user_id');
    });
}
```

But I get the error message:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bootstrap`.`#sql-512_179`
, CONSTRAINT `designs_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)) (SQL: alter table `designs` add constraint designs_user_
id_foreign foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`))
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: According to your `users` migration, the id column isn't unsigned (although I don't know for certain whether 'increments' is unsigned or not by default in Laravel, it really should be) so maybe that's your issue?

Comment: I'm not sure thats true - when I use increments it is setup as unsigned (thats in laravel 3 though).

Answer (score 0):

In mysql 'increments' is int(10) with 'Unsigned' Attribute.
But If you just add new column and try to reference it and get SQLSTATE[23000] - 1452 error message, try to insert a valid reference (key). Or Empty both table.